# WinAPI OpenQuery Producing errors

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm using the [winapi-rs crate](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs) and attempting to get the cpu usage, however I'm not even able to make it that far.

PdhCollectQueryData is returning '-2147481643' when converted hex, then to the error code is it '0x800007D5 (PDH_NO_DATA)   No data to return.' which is the issue I'm facing.

Could someone help determine what I'm doing wrong to cause 'x800007D5 (PDH_NO_DATA)     No data to return'? I can get this working in C++ (code supplied below) but when attempting to convert it to Rust code, it isn't going well at all.

```rust
use wmi::{COMLibrary, Variant, WMIConnection};
use std::{collections::HashMap, ptr::null};
use winapi::{ctypes::{c_char, c_void},um::{pdh::*, winnt::{LPCSTR}}};

#[cfg(windows)]
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>>  {

    const CPU_TIME: LPCSTR = "\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time".as_ptr() as *const i8;

    unsafe  
    {
        //cpuQuery
        let mut hquery: PDH_HQUERY = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let hquery_address: *mut PDH_HQUERY = &mut hquery as *mut *mut _ as *mut *mut c_void;

        //cpuCounter
        let mut hcounter: PDH_HCOUNTER = std::ptr::null_mut();
        let hcounter_address: *mut PDH_HCOUNTER = &mut hcounter as *mut *mut _ as *mut *mut c_void;

        //open query
        PdhOpenQueryA(null(), 0, hquery_address);

        PdhAddCounterA(hquery, CPU_TIME, 0, hcounter_address);
        
        PdhCollectQueryData(hquery);

    }
    Ok(())
}
```

An example of what's returned for some of the values once the program has finished if I println the values:

```
hquery: 0x2541b495e00
hquery_address: 0xce3dafef00
PdhOpenQueryA: 0
PdhCollectQueryData -2147481643
```

Working C++ code (taken from another Stack Overflow answer and works fine when I run it)

```cpp
#include <TCHAR.h>
#include <pdh.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>  

#pragma comment(lib, "pdh.lib")
using namespace std;

static PDH_HQUERY cpuQuery;
static PDH_HCOUNTER cpuTotal = NULL;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &cpuQuery);
    PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, L"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time", NULL, &cpuTotal);
    PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE counterVal;

    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
    PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, NULL, &counterVal);
    cout << counterVal.doubleValue << "\n";

    getchar();
}
```

So, as the C++ code is working the counter is there. What am I doing wrong with the rust code for the query collect to not work correctly and produce 'x800007D5 (PDH_NO_DATA)  No data to return.'??

Comment: I did have it all converted, but removed a chunk of it until I got the code that was producing the first error PdhCollectQueryData(hquery). 

PdhCollectQueryData(hquery) is giving an error code: 0x800007D5 (PDH_NO_DATA) No data to return and I cannot figure out why that's happening. I have update the question to hopefully make it more clear, my bad :)

Comment: There's no error handling or error reporting anywhere. This is wrong in C++ already and most certainly against anything Rust stands for. The first step in porting poor C++ code is usually adding error reporting.

Comment: @IInspectable yeah I understand that, the C++ code isnt great and I took it from a different SO answer as I was just wanting to see if I could get this to work tbh. Will definetly work on cleaning the Rust code up with error handling, appologise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a literal translation of your C++ example into Rust using the [`winapi` crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi).

As IInspectable said in the comments, you'll need to add some error handling, in this case I've added some `assert_eq!`.

```rust
use std::ptr;
// winapi = { version = "0.3.9", features = ["pdh", "winerror"] }
use winapi::{ctypes::c_char, shared::winerror::ERROR_SUCCESS, um::pdh::*};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut cpu_query: PDH_HQUERY = ptr::null_mut();
        let mut cpu_total: PDH_HCOUNTER = ptr::null_mut();

        let err = PdhOpenQueryA(ptr::null(), 0, &mut cpu_query);
        assert_eq!(err, ERROR_SUCCESS as i32);

        let err = PdhAddCounterA(
            cpu_query,
            b"\\Processor(_Total)\\% Processor Time\0".as_ptr() as *const c_char,
            0,
            &mut cpu_total,
        );
        assert_eq!(err, ERROR_SUCCESS as i32);

        let mut counter_val: PDH_FMT_COUNTERVALUE = std::mem::zeroed();
        let err = PdhCollectQueryData(cpu_query);
        assert_eq!(err, ERROR_SUCCESS as i32);

        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));

        let err = PdhCollectQueryData(cpu_query);
        assert_eq!(err, ERROR_SUCCESS as i32);

        let err = PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(
            cpu_total,
            PDH_FMT_DOUBLE,
            ptr::null_mut(),
            &mut counter_val,
        );
        assert_eq!(err, ERROR_SUCCESS as i32);

        println!("{:?}", counter_val.u.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This works perfectly and I'll deffo add more error handling. I've still got a lot to learn about Rust evidently, but this is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, happy I could help :) if you're learning Rust, then you're definitely doing it the hard way by using the Windows API directly

Comment: I'm newish, I've built other little bits in Rust (don't worry, to a much better standard than what I posted in my question) but I'm very new to systems programming and especailly the Windows API. But, I'm subborn and went from basic programs and solving LeetCode questions in Rust to this lmao.
Thanks again mate.